# AutoCAD User Converting Rectangular Joints to Curves

Tags: modifiers, objects, bezier-curves

I have made a bunch of rectangular joints which i want to convert to curves please see attachment. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sfYR.png)

Comment: are you looking for a Curve Object (a spline with control points, or Bezier) -- or is a polyline (vertices+edges connecting them) OK? because ctrl+shift+B bevels two edges if they share a vertex. To get a fillet use mouse wheel to add segments, during that operation